# How to circumvent TypeError caused by static shapes while still sticking with `[None]` shape when using Tensorflow 1.x?

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I was attempting to fit softmax probability with maximum likelihood using `TensorFlow 1.x`, I bumped into the error message:

`"TypeError: Expected int32, got None of type '_Message' instead."`

The error comes from `x.get_shape().as_list()[0]` in function **p(x)**. I fixed the error after changing `x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])` into `x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [BATCH_SIZE])`, where `BATCH_SIZE` is a fixed number.

How do I solve this error if I want to stick with  `x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])` ?

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
with tf.variable_scope('param'):
    theta = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(100), dtype=tf.float32, name='theta')


with tf.variable_scope('loss'):
    def p(x):
        softmax = tf.ones([x.get_shape().as_list()[0], 1]) * tf.math.softmax(theta)
        idx_x = tf.stack([tf.range(x.get_shape().as_list()[0], dtype=tf.int64), x-1], axis=1)
        return tf.gather_nd(softmax,idx_x)

    def softmaxLoss(x):
        return tf.reduce_mean(-tf.math.log(p(x)))

var_list = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, 'param')
x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])
prob_op = p(x)
log_loss = softmaxLoss(x)
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `tf.shape()` to get the dynamic shape  of a tensor. [`tf.shape()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/shape) returns shape as a Tensor object. In your case use it like this:

```py
tf.shape(x)[0]
```

So your code would be:

```py
def p(x):
    softmax = tf.ones([tf.shape(x)[0], 1]) * tf.math.softmax(theta)
    idx_x = tf.stack([tf.range(tf.shape(x)[0], dtype=tf.int64), x-1], axis=1)
    return tf.gather_nd(softmax,idx_x)
```